# Converting SQL Server code to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to concatenate two integers as the default value in a third field. My create table in SQL Server works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE MEI_Tbl
(
MEI_ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
SRC tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
HEI_ID AS (Cast (SRC as varchar)+ Cast (MEI_ID as varchar))
);
```

but when I try to create it in MySQL, I cannot find the equivalent for the concatenation of the two integers (Line 5 HEI_ID...).
**
I am aware of changing IDENTITY (1,1) to AUTO_INCREMENT for MySQL.
**
I have also tried several concat methods, but to no avail.

MySQL seems happier if I define the datatype for HEI_ID, and I have done so as varchar and int but again no success.

I have spent too much time reading about tool kits to convert SQL Server to MySQL. I just want to create the table in MySQL.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support computed columns.  Instead, you can use a view:

```
CREATE TABLE MEI_Tbl (
    MEI_ID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SRC tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 2
);

CREATE VIEW v_MEI_Tbl as
    SELECT MEI_ID, SRC,
           CONCAT(src, mei_d) as HEI_ID 
    FROM MEI_Tbl
);
```

Then query from the view.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Your first sentence ("MySQL does not support computed columns.") is not something I had read. Nor did I come across it in my research. Your suggestion for a workaround also makes sense.